# How I can change the provider name of an app in the apple store?

Tags: ios, app-store

How I can change the provider name of an app in the apple store?

Comment: What you mean by provider name? Didn't get it?

Comment: the name of the developer, sry :( i want to change them!

Comment: I think you're looking for this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074232/changing-or-removing-developer-name-in-app-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the **Seller** name then -

On the current **Contact** page, the **Contracts and Legal** category includes **Request Name/Address update**. Try that.

For more info - [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074232/changing-or-removing-developer-name-in-app-store)

Comment: i cannot update it, because it has a light gray backgrounnd :(