# How can I change my seller name In App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Heres the issue, Im 17 years old and my uncle created an account for me for publishing my apps because Im very interested in developing in iOS, obviously the account is at his name because at first I tried to pay one at my name with his credit card and I got rejected because the names didnt match so we made the one of him.

My recently publish is at his name (in the sellers name), the copyright its at my name but the sellers dont and I want to know if its possible to change it for mine or maybe not my name, only a nickname.... and if dont, where can I send an E-mail or something, please you can imagine how frustrating is that the sellers name is not yours when you put all your effort..... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only change the developper name by contacting Apple support :

[see this blog article](http://appdevelopermagazine.com/419/2013/6/10/Developers-Can-Now-Transfer-Apps-Around/)

and this answer on SO :

[Changing or Removing Developer Name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074232/changing-or-removing-developer-name-in-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the iTunes Connect Developer Guide, specifically the section about transferring apps to another organization: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Disclaimer: I haven't used this method myself. I've transferred apps by letting and old developer account expire, since it was the most convenient, the least hassle, and the only option available at that time. But that may not be the case for you, so definitely look up the transfer option.