# Change iOS App provider (By) name after submission?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have published an iOS app in iTunes Store and it is in live now. Somehow i want to change the name as that i specified in the screenshot below. I can't find the By xxxx detail in iTunes App information page.

Thanks in advance and can anyone provide suggestion to change it's name. I also want to know do we need to upload new binary build to change app's information including screenshot, app name etc.,

[image: iTunes screenshot]

Comment: if your app in ready for sale , you can't do any thing , if you add the new build on that time you can change anything , I am not sure we can modify the app name

Comment: can we change the name that comes after (By), actually my app name comes before (By). i think it may be a provider name.

Comment: but your question is good one

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but if you want to change the "**APP PROVIDER**" name you need to contact the apple support.

Find your question and choose **contact us** option.

please find detail on this link.

[support/account/](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/)

Morever , you can also refer this SO question.

> [changing-or-removing-developer-name-in-app-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074232/changing-or-removing-developer-name-in-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

**For After By - Ready for Sale**

> You can change the following store metadata while an app’s version has
>   the **Ready for Sale** status:
>
> - Copyright, Routing App Coverage File
> - Description, What’s New in this Version
> - Support URL, Marketing URL, and Privacy Policy URL
> - App Store Contact Information Language support, including adding new languages
>     and changing the default language

**For Before By - Upto Waiting for Review**

> To rename existing application on App Store you can create **New Version** and
>   then enter **app-name** in `Name` field. the `app-name<=255` char on max.

Source: [Apple iOS Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html)

Comment: I am not sure but changing providername is not included as Metadata. apple will take automatically according to associated account.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to **change your name** you can open a Ticket through the link: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

I changed my surname in the account display. They will ask you some proof documents such as ID. It take some days to completely fix.

But if you need to **transfer** you app to another account you can follow this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).